# Use cheerio in Vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, cheerio

I'd like to scrape a website in a Vue application using [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).
The error I get back is as follows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $.find is not a function
```

### Code

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  created() {
    this.fetchUrl();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchUrl() {
      axios
        .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://stackoverflow.com/")
        .then(response => {
          const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
          const span = $.find(".fs-headline2");
          console.log(span);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

### Sandbox

In this case, I'm trying to scrape the title **'For developers, by developers'** headline of the homepage of Stack Overflow.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-boyd-u4ew7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark&view=editor

Comment: did you finish your project ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you discovered, there is no `$.find` method (although there is a `$().find()`).
To find all `.fs-headline2` elements, do `$('.fs-headline2')` instead:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
const span = $(".fs-headline2");
```

[updated codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-nightingale-hzbjk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)